# Android - firebase get all parent object in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: firebase state]

Following the image I want to retrieve all projects that inside users has my getUid() set to true and use in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

I'm using a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

I'm trying with this but it's not working

```
    Query postsQuery = mDatabase.child("projects").child("users").orderByChild(getUid()).equalTo(true);
    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Project, ProjectViewHolder>(Project.class, R.layout.item_project,
            ProjectViewHolder.class, postsQuery) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(final ProjectViewHolder viewHolder, final Project model, final int position) {
            final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position);
            Log.d(TAG, model.name + "");
            viewHolder.bindToPost(model);

        }
    };
    mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I think the problem is that I need parent object (Projects) and not users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go a step higher in the tree by using `getParent()` method like this:

```
final DatabaseReference postRef = getRef(position).getParent();
String name = postRef.child("name").getValue(String.class);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks !! i've solved

`DatabaseReference keyRef = mDatabase.child("users").child(getUid()).child("projects");
        DatabaseReference dataRef = mDatabase.child("projects");


        mAdapter = new FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter<Project, ProjectViewHolder>(Project.class, R.layout.item_project, ProjectViewHolder.class, keyRef, dataRef) {
            @Override
            public void populateViewHolder(ProjectViewHolder viewHolder, Project item, int position) {
                Log.d(TAG, item.name + "");
            }
        };

        mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [FirebaseIndexRecyclerAdapter](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-with-indexed-data)

In this case, your key references will be another node where you set which projects are linked to the user.

```
"user_projects": {
    "UID": {
        "project_1":true,
        "project_4":true,
    }
}
```